# Jquery mouseover that rearranges classes within a div then resets with mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

**EDIT** - 
The correct solution can be found [here](https://codepen.io/swank/pen/zYOyOda). Going off of [Taplar's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1586174/taplar) suggestion. I made two additional classes that duplicate the active and inactive but with !important property.

**Original Post**

I am new to the coding world and am going crazy trying to figure this out. I found and am trying to modify this code posted at [Codepen](https://codepen.io/codewunder/pen/Bnspb/).

On load, I would like to have .premium display as 'active' and have .standard and .platinum display as 'inactive'. Then on mouseover(), rearrange the classes so that what is being moused-over would have the 'active' class and the others 'inactive'. Lastly, when mouseleave() is triggered reset each div to the original default active and inactive.

**HTML**

```html
<section class="pen">
        <div class="plans">
            <div class="plandis standard inactive"></div>
            <div class="plandis premium active"></div>
            <div class="plandis platinum inactive"></div>
     </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```css
.pen {
  max-width: 635px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: 1s appear 1 forwards;
  -moz-animation: 1s appear 1 forwards;
  -o-animation: 1s appear 1 forwards;
  animation: 1s appear 1 forwards;
}
.plans {
  max-width: 635px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.plandis {
  width: 202px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  height: inherit;
  margin: 0 7px 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.plandis.active {
  width: 282px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.plandis.inactive {
  width: 162px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
.plandis.premium {
  background-color:red;
  background-size: cover;
}
.plandis.standard {
  background-color:blue;
  background-size: cover;
}
.plandis.platinum {
  background-color:green;
  background-size: cover;
}
.plandis:last-of-type {
  margin: 0;
}
@media all and (min-width: 900px) {
  .pen {
    max-width: 890px;
  }
  .plandis {
    width: 286px;
  }
  .plandis.inactive {
    width: 246px;
  }
  .plandis.active {
    width: 366px;
  }
  .plans {
    max-width: 890px;
    height: 600px;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 660px) {
  .pen {
    max-width: 335px;
  }
  .plandis {
    width: 101px;
  }
  .plandis.inactive {
    width: 61px;
  }
  .plandis.active {
    width: 181px;
  }
  .plans {
    max-width: 335px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes appear {
  15% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes appear {
  15% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes appear {
  15% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes appear {
  15% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

**JS**

```js
$('.plandis').each(function() {
    $(this).mouseover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.plans').children('.plandis').not('.active').addClass('inactive');
    });
    $(this).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $('.plans').children('.plandis').not('.active').removeClass('inactive');
    });
});
```

I have tried to manipulate the code multiple times but to no avail. So hopefully someone will be able to help me out!

Comment: Mouseover is going to trigger for every mouse move over the elements, which is most likely unnecessary work.  You most likely want mouseenter instead.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! Unfortunately, this doesn't remove active from the .premium div if either of the other divs are first mouseentered and on mouseleave all are lose active and inactive. Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/swank/pen/eYOQxeM) of your suggestion.

Comment: Keep in mind I was not providing a suggestion for a solution.  Simply a suggestion about a performance concern with an approach you were trying to take.

Comment: Ahh, I see thank you for the suggestion. I have edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I went about this suggested solution slightly different.  Rather than toggling the active and inactive classes, I added a third class of "ignore".

```
.plandis.active:not(.ignore),
.plandis.inactive:hover {
}
```

The css rule for active was changed to also check that the element does not have the `ignore` class.  Also, the element should be active if it is `inactive`, but is hovered on.

At that point, we just have to add the ignore class to any active element that we are not currently hovering over.

```js
var $allPlandis = $('.plandis')
  .on('mouseenter', function() {
    $allPlandis.not(this).filter('.active').addClass('ignore');
  })
  .on('mouseleave', function() {
    $allPlandis.filter('.ignore').removeClass('ignore');
  });
```

```css
.pen {
  max-width: 635px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: 1s appear 1 forwards;
  -moz-animation: 1s appear 1 forwards;
  -o-animation: 1s appear 1 forwards;
  animation: 1s appear 1 forwards;
}

.plans {
  max-width: 635px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.plandis {
  width: 202px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  height: inherit;
  margin: 0 7px 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.plandis.active:not(.ignore),
.plandis.inactive:hover {
  width: 282px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.plandis.inactive {
  width: 162px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.plandis.premium {
  background-color: red;
  background-size: cover;
}

.plandis.standard {
  background-color: blue;
  background-size: cover;
}

.plandis.platinum {
  background-color: green;
  background-size: cover;
}

.plandis:last-of-type {
  margin: 0;
}

@media all and (min-width: 900px) {
  .pen {
    max-width: 890px;
  }
  .plandis {
    width: 286px;
  }
  .plandis.inactive {
    width: 246px;
  }
  .plandis.active {
    width: 366px;
  }
  .plans {
    max-width: 890px;
    height: 600px;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 660px) {
  .pen {
    max-width: 335px;
  }
  .plandis {
    width: 101px;
  }
  .plandis.inactive {
    width: 61px;
  }
  .plandis.active {
    width: 181px;
  }
  .plans {
    max-width: 335px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes appear {
  15% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes appear {
  15% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes appear {
  15% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes appear {
  15% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="pen">
  <div class="plans">
    <div class="plandis standard inactive"></div>
    <div class="plandis premium active"></div>
    <div class="plandis platinum inactive"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The snippet runner here appears to work, however there is some display oddity with the CSS as it appears making the first one active and the second one inactive pushes the third one down on the page, rather than staying on the same line.

Comment: **Thank you!** This helped me figure out what I needed to do! I posted the answer below

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution can be found [here](https://codepen.io/swank/pen/zYOyOda). Going off of [Taplar's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1586174/taplar) suggestion. I made two additional classes that duplicate the active and inactive classes but with !important property.

**HTML**

```js
$('.plandis').each(function() {
  $(this).mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('activejq');
    $('.plans').children('.plandis').not('.activejq').addClass('inactivejq');
  });
  $(this).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('activejq');
    $('.plans').children('.plandis').not('.activejq').removeClass('inactivejq');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #000000;
}

.pen {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: 1s appear 1 forwards;
  -moz-animation: 1s appear 1 forwards;
  -o-animation: 1s appear 1 forwards;
  animation: 1s appear 1 forwards;
}

.plans {
  max-width: 635px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.plandis {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  height: inherit;
  margin: 0 7px 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.active {
  width: 282px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.inactive {
  width: 162px;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.inactivejq {
  width: 246px !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.activejq {
  width: 366px !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

.plandis.premium {
  background-color: red;
  background-size: cover;
}

.plandis.standard {
  background-color: blue;
  background-size: cover;
}

.plandis.platinum {
  background-color: green;
  background-size: cover;
}

.plandis:last-of-type {
  margin: 0;
}

@media all and (min-width: 900px) {
  .pen {
    max-width: 890px;
  }
  .plandis {
    width: 286px;
  }
  .inactive {
    width: 246px;
  }
  .active {
    width: 366px;
  }
  .plans {
    max-width: 890px;
    height: 600px;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 660px) {
  .pen {
    max-width: 335px;
  }
  .plandis {
    width: 101px;
  }
  .inactive {
    width: 61px;
  }
  .active {
    width: 181px;
  }
  .inactivejq {
    width: 61px !important;
  }
  .activejq {
    width: 181px !important;
  }
  .plans {
    max-width: 335px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes appear {
  15% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes appear {
  15% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes appear {
  15% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes appear {
  15% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <section class="pen">
    <div class="plans">
      <div class="plandis standard inactive"></div>
      <div class="plandis premium active"></div>
      <div class="plandis platinum inactive"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```